# regex - python extracting email header names

Tags: python, regex

hi am looking for a way to extract header names (what is in bold) from this block of text (originaly from mbox file)
i tried this regex that worked on sublime text regex search but didnt work on python
^\w+-?(\w+)?-?(\w+)?:

```
rgex = re.findall('^\w+-?(\w+)?-?(\w+)?:', mail);
```

THIS IS WHAT IS INSIDE mail

> **X-Apparently-To**: test@yahoo.com; Thu, 09 Jun 2016 13:41:21 +0000
>   
>  **Return-Path**: 
>   
>  **Received-SPF**: pass (domain of yahoo.com designates 72.30.235.45 as permitted sender)
>   
>  **Received**: from 127.0.0.1  (EHLO n3-vm9.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com) (72.30.235.45)   by mta1287.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with SMTPS; Thu, 09 Jun
>   
>  2016 13:41:21 +0000
>   
>  **DKIM-Signature**: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoo-inc.com; s=yibm; t=1465479679; 
>   
>  **To**: test@yahoo.com
>   
>  **From**: "Yahoo" 
>   
>  **Reply-To**: "Yahoo" 
>   
>  **X-YMailISG**: PCypxycWLDvGv4Bg8ShrtzVYi3vpFMAjYaqWyWybcVJ_ZQff  eyquyqb..Qu6UKhX_Tyz5b3da2iDtRStJpVnNulZHOb8GznJQTCKk9sjvboS 
>   KsbzY4E1uScWz0Ieo0jjG0YHrB1dTCzOSeMiPNumCCFS1sR3_SkyMBGG_D2D 
>   wWtdRducxLa2YgEMMubVpMtNJMBv.bwk0.E.jQNEy8I3LnJEqcDpmIUM7bZL 
>   XgkEFz7yl1Zo6Sj4r0z6pGlVIFOql7uG9Bwq2VJoK1Q1upKJUOBfQqzf64y2 
>   9fXLnQsWENpZloxwncGzLhdzEYGgE3xNuFV8QFxZGXyvtKZFoykH49M03URN 
>   jtx8Yg6ypjyRbBIRVJGVFbjAvW6io3yeyIFh042jlgYQtLxbneFA60hn9ifT 
>   Mit3bQ5l7Tginw0OgRM2cbqLo0tEZFt9vlN597Z3vPGwsVdBcTp9wnk6orj2 
>   TqjEpAmODy3Yru2HzDP7Dbwq9CGaIozUm91VNWqw5Dy7AMQEsuvnBop7Fflk 
>   G21m1WKMBgrS.2bOLQ4797E09LjlyyoWI9FouUNNhDljnPPf2AeKUKzauctw 
>   ULOQPveWAm4lDsNLMp5yvXDYNIe5HMor84SVd8_xF3Icna1PAftXGzJUHrXK 
>   NZSEN_VO0GprGfaNQg4uSW_0wXFXwC6TYQ4CMjz53o0qNGpILogVfRLwFCFL 
>   DtW8nimkLLsNzmDajzJsR_juA86Orw2NE5ED4qdpPxmyxyrXYOQPu3O6zeYf 
>   7mBzU0aX7VHJUxJ4L3HdB9qTjbTaCdnySrnjGtd7u9Cn9yRJirDNeg3UA82P 
>   PeA1ZDfc0vKdrn5QI6e6YKa2TTt7Dspy3jObgSapH5epc3LyQVyN7yjpxrq_ 
>   MXAbpqedjUfcwq3c7lpt8xxUxy.MXWg0fJO059xijvb_sYTaQTGUWAMeVU.6 
>   IW.hSksejwpn._CgE9Kqabbk5qgYIdYRW1pmz5OBYh0skCX1TrFRuxbGvDit 
>   R_wr.wbTpJGiSST.b0ZetmgN72bVvlRtmNPw1Dk.zxaacXxhGSMWupPUDLJZ 
>   OMrap2ax8oiQrxT3jIhk8seIkaNJ.tGUhlPx6G4lJJaz0g89LmjBaEjGUG8P 
>   W3Phh9db3hjxUIX5UC0jg5ai2XZ7u_wXn2Muk61N1eRCZ0oA2S25YDPK1dh. 
>   3VQ6pH8SSBxVkQHUJXbZUNqLAzi5V5wRS7oeitXERGgA2DiZB268.rJxS7di 
>   OMT5eGoITG4LnAo1M3nsVQ6xceHDd4v6KD9KfBgTHX_iLUv_skCv4dVUgVvj 
>   edKOFiOMHBTpJ9J9BECjTTzEUpc.fCNUcRwSsiSkqbRhUsAdCbxQZir3Nb1Z 
>   6FzI6J2eNqpj4azjmDeI15R8MyN7VFc6bl6pCZySk2Tx5SQESDm.sVkADSVR 
>   pI2nuscEjU3xo_qGUxbh5mbAA17K2zYpcFXaOce8_9Eszos5pURCcdtBYUqI 
>   I_DOtvNe.zWY1ShRcr9ZzTj3ibmc7NBmvumhVMjqirb12mfJ6oxHv8d86gze 
>   HtAJmJghczUg5otSzdxSgEJJxjMZrzSidJ9FP.gPiPWtuukz82YpZ32MnCVs
>    6.V2DRxpUmZa31KH93QSEzwMlCn3FFTLBv9izcjoFP81yeAn.3QloF8XIC3K  WmtXtloyeGjuygAhlkd_prXmMGGC5JmPlY8xu4k1NavkdDh6pG6zIkt83Wsd  p.D.0BgM
>   
>  **X-Originating-IP**: [75.30.245.45]
>   
>  **Authentication-Results**: mta1287.mail.ne1.yahoo.com  from=yahoo-inc.com; domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=yahoo-inc.com;
>   dkim=pass (ok)

Comment: Well... Try something like [`(?![^\s:]*\d+:\d+)([^\s:]+):`](https://regex101.com/r/wY3qH2/1).

Comment: Is there a reason not to just use the `email` package to parse the headers (and thus get header names) ?

Comment: donkopotamus- yes in my case it has to be from a certain file

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew- thanks that will do :)

Comment: @user1731805 You can just read the file and pass the text to an `email.Parser` (which will read rfc822 style messages)

Comment: Oh, the point is that the keys always appear at the beginning of the line, right?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew can u help me out with the value of each header rather that header name

Comment: I wonder if that can be better done with the `email` module... See https://ideone.com/o4KtM7

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew ill try it although didn't work for me in my first try

Comment: Just use `msg.values()`. I think donkopotamus' idea is the best.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew i keep getting empty list with this pastebin.com/8H0kHv00 using email module

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/o4KtM7

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach than devising an appropriate regex might be to use a more appropriate tool that comes with python ... the [`email.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html) module, which is designed to parse rcf822 messages such as this.

```
>>> from email import parser
>>> txt = """X-Apparently-To: test@yahoo.com; Thu, 09 Jun 2016 13:41:21 +0000 
... Return-Path: 
... Received-SPF: pass (domain of yahoo.com designates 72.30.235.45 as permitted sender) 
... Received: from 127.0.0.1 (EHLO n3-vm9.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com) (72.30.235.45) by mta1287.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with SMTPS; Thu, 09 Jun 2016 13:41:21 +0000
... DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoo-inc.com; s=yibm; t=1465479679; 
... To: test@yahoo.com 
... From: "Yahoo" 
... Reply-To: "Yahoo"
... X-YMailISG: PCypxy...
... X-Originating-IP: [75.30.245.45] 
... Authentication-Results: mta1287.mail.ne1.yahoo.com from=yahoo-inc.com; domainkeys=neutral (no sig); from=yahoo-inc.com; dkim=pass (ok)
... """
>>> msg = parser.Parser().parsestr(txt, headersonly=True)
>>> print(msg.keys())
['X-Apparently-To', 'Return-Path', 'Received-SPF', 'Received', 'DKIM-Signature', 'To', 'From', 'Reply-To' 'X-YMailISG', 'X-Originating-IP', 'Authentication-Results']
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew because I couldn't be bothered polluting the answer with the next three very large headers ...

Comment: :) You could truncate them at least, that baffled me a bit.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's a better idea :-)

Comment: @user1731805 That's because the first three lines in this pastebin are **not part of the email message** ...  if you strip those it parses just fine.  (the first two lines are part of the mbox format, not sure about the other extra line)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a regex over the entire mbox file then a regex will not work - you're going to have to write a program.  The reason is that the body of the message has the potential to have tokens that will match exactly what a header token will look like.

Assuming that you're ONLY running the regex over the header portion of the mbox file(s) then, looking at the [email RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-7) (section 2.2.) then the following regex should work:

> '^([^:]+):'

Answer (score 0):

Your `'^\w+-?(\w+)?-?(\w+)?:'` regex matches the beginning of a string (`^`), then 1+ word chars, followed by an optional `-`, then 1+ word chars are captured into an optional Group 1 (and those are returned by `re.findall` as the first item in each tuple returned as a list), followed with an optional hyphen, again a capture group matching 1+ word chars (optional, but still returned as the 2nd item in the tuple), and a `:` at the end. It would not work because of `^`, optional `-` between `\w` and 2 capture groups.

**If the input you get complies with the rfc 8222 message style, you should consider switching to a `from email import parser` solution given above.**

Alternatively, it seems to me you can just capture all characters other than whitespace and a colon up to a colon that is followed with whitespace *at the beginning of a line*:

```
r"^([^\s:]+):\s"
```

And use it with `re.findall` and `re.M` flag.

**Regex explanation**:

- `^` - start of line (as `re.M` makes `^` match the position after a newline) or start of string)
- `([^\s:]+)` - Capture group 1 matching 1+ characters other than whitespace and a colon
- `:` - a colon
- `\s` - a whitespace character.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT2sE5/1)

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/ni3MkV) where `re.findall` returns only the *captured* texts:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^([^\s:]+):\s', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "X-Apparently-To: test@yahoo.com; Thu, 09 Jun 2016 13:41:21 +0000 \nReturn-Path: \nReceived-SPF: pass (domain of yahoo.com designates 72.30.235.45 as permitted sender) \nReceived: from 127.0.0.1 (EHLO n3-vm9.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com) (72.30.235.45) by mta1287.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with SMTPS; Thu, 09 Jun \n2016 13:41:21 +0000 \nDKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoo-inc.com; s=yibm; t=1465479679; \nTo: test@yahoo.com \nFrom: \"Yahoo\" \nReply-To: \"Yahoo\" \nX-YMailISG: PCypxycWLDvGv4Bg8ShrtzVYi3vpFMAjYaqWyWybcVJ_ZQff eyquyqb..Qu6UKhX_Tyz5b3da2iDtRStJpVnNulZHOb8GznJQTCKk9sjvboS KsbzY4E1uScWz0Ieo0jjG0YHrB1dTCzOSeMiPNumCCFS1sR3_SkyMBGG_D2D wWtdRducxLa2YgEMMubVpMtNJMBv.bwk0.E.jQNEy8I3LnJEqcDpmIUM7bZL XgkEFz7yl1Zo6Sj4r0z6pGlVIFOql7uG9Bwq2VJoK1Q1upKJUOBfQqzf64y2 9fXLnQsWENpZloxwncGzLhdzEYGgE3xNuFV8QFxZGXyvtKZFoykH49M03URN jtx8Yg6ypjyRbBIRVJGVFbjAvW6io3yeyIFh042jlgYQtLxbneFA60hn9ifT Mit3bQ5l7Tginw0OgRM2cbqLo0tEZFt9vlN597Z3vPGwsVdBcTp9wnk6orj2 TqjEpAmODy3Yru2HzDP7Dbwq9CGaIozUm91VNWqw5Dy7AMQEsuvnBop7Fflk G21m1WKMBgrS.2bOLQ4797E09LjlyyoWI9FouUNNhDljnPPf2AeKUKzauctw ULOQPveWAm4lDsNLMp5yvXDYNIe5HMor84SVd8_xF3Icna1PAftXGzJUHrXK NZSEN_VO0GprGfaNQg4uSW_0wXFXwC6TYQ4CMjz53o0qNGpILogVfRLwFCFL DtW8nimkLLsNzmDajzJsR_juA86Orw2NE5ED4qdpPxmyxyrXYOQPu3O6zeYf 7mBzU0aX7VHJUxJ4L3HdB9qTjbTaCdnySrnjGtd7u9Cn9yRJirDNeg3UA82P PeA1ZDfc0vKdrn5QI6e6YKa2TTt7Dspy3jObgSapH5epc3LyQVyN7yjpxrq_ MXAbpqedjUfcwq3c7lpt8xxUxy.MXWg0fJO059xijvb_sYTaQTGUWAMeVU.6 IW.hSksejwpn._CgE9Kqabbk5qgYIdYRW1pmz5OBYh0skCX1TrFRuxbGvDit R_wr.wbTpJGiSST.b0ZetmgN72bVvlRtmNPw1Dk.zxaacXxhGSMWupPUDLJZ OMrap2ax8oiQrxT3jIhk8seIkaNJ.tGUhlPx6G4lJJaz0g89LmjBaEjGUG8P W3Phh9db3hjxUIX5UC0jg5ai2XZ7u_wXn2Muk61N1eRCZ0oA2S25YDPK1dh. 3VQ6pH8SSBxVkQHUJXbZUNqLAzi5V5wRS7oeitXERGgA2DiZB268.rJxS7di OMT5eGoITG4LnAo1M3nsVQ6xceHDd4v6KD9KfBgTHX_iLUv_skCv4dVUgVvj edKOFiOMHBTpJ9J9BECjTTzEUpc.fCNUcRwSsiSkqbRhUsAdCbxQZir3Nb1Z 6FzI6J2eNqpj4azjmDeI15R8MyN7VFc6bl6pCZySk2Tx5SQESDm.sVkADSVR pI2nuscEjU3xo_qGUxbh5mbAA17K2zYpcFXaOce8_9Eszos5pURCcdtBYUqI I_DOtvNe.zWY1ShRcr9ZzTj3ibmc7NBmvumhVMjqirb12mfJ6oxHv8d86gze HtAJmJghczUg5otSzdxSgEJJxjMZrzSidJ9FP.gPiPWtuukz82YpZ32MnCVs 6.V2DRxpUmZa31KH93QSEzwMlCn3FFTLBv9izcjoFP81yeAn.3QloF8XIC3K WmtXtloyeGjuygAhlkd_prXmMGGC5JmPlY8xu4k1NavkdDh6pG6zIkt83Wsd p.D.0BgM \nX-Originating-IP: [75.30.245.45] \nAuthentication-Results: mta1287.mail.ne1.yahoo.com from=yahoo-inc.com; domainkeys=neutral (no sig); from=yahoo-inc.com; dkim=pass (ok)"
print(p.findall(test_str))
```

**UPDATE**

Now, since you requested to get values only, you can use the same approach, but just strip the keys when found and add the values to the resulting list:

```
txt = "YOUR_STRING_HERE"
values = []                    # Resulting value list
start_matching = False         # Bool flag to start matching the key-value pairs
val = ""                       # Temp string to keep multiline values
for line in txt.split("\n"):   #  Split the input into lines
    if re.match(r"[^\s:]+:\s", line.strip()): # Check if the entry is found
        start_matching = True   # Start matching
        if val:                 # If a val is initialized, 
            values.append(val)  #    we save it to our list
            val = ""            # Reset the temp string value
        val += re.sub(r"^[^\s:]+:\s", "", line.strip()) # Append the value string start
    else:
        if start_matching:      # If matching has started,
            val += "{}\n".format(line.strip()) # add the line to the value found
print(values)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/o4KtM7)

Answer (score 0):

Python provides the email package that can do those low-level tasks for you, but if you want to learn email headers the hard way, the reference is the [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) (formely RFC822)

Among other sensible information, you find the definition of header fields:

> Header fields are lines beginning with a field name, followed by a
> colon (":"), followed by a field body, and terminated by CRLF.  A
> field name MUST be composed of printable US-ASCII characters (i.e.,
> characters that have values between 33 and 126, inclusive), except
> colon.  A field body may be composed of printable US-ASCII characters
> as well as the space (SP, ASCII value 32) and horizontal tab (HTAB,
> ASCII value 9) characters (together known as the white space
> characters, WSP).  A field body MUST NOT include CR and LF except
> when used in "folding" and "unfolding"

Folding is later defined by:

> the field body portion of a header field can be split into a
> multiple-line representation; this is called "folding".  The general
> rule is that wherever this specification allows for folding white
> space (not simply WSP characters), a CRLF may be inserted before any
> WSP.

That means that:

- when a line does not start with a WSP (`\s` in a regex) the start of line up to a column is the header name.
- when a line starts with a WSP, it is a continuation line.

So this regex should be enough: `'([\x21-\x7e]+?):'`